# Converting Matplotlib's filled contour plot (contourf_plot) to GeoJSON

Tags: python, polygon, geojson, contour, contourf

I am working on a project where I have successfully generated filled contour plots using plt.contourf in Matplotlib in a Google Colab environment. Now, I am attempting to convert these filled contour polygons into GeoJSON for seamless integration with Folium.

```
import numpy as np
import folium
from folium import plugins
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex, Normalize

# Specify the URL of the NetCDF file
url = "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/socd/mecb/sar/AKDEMO_products/APL_winds/tropical/2024/SH052024_BELAL/STAR_SAR_20240116013937_SH052024_05S_MERGED_FIX_3km.nc"

# Download the NetCDF file content
response = requests.get(url)
nc_content = BytesIO(response.content)
# Open the NetCDF file using xarray
dataset = xr.open_dataset(nc_content)

# Access the 'sar_wind' variable
sar_wind = dataset['sar_wind'].values

# Access the 'latitude' and 'longitude' variables
latitude = dataset['latitude'].values
longitude = dataset['longitude'].values
# Set iso values for filled contours
iso_values_filled = np.linspace(np.min(sar_wind), np.max(sar_wind), 11)  # One extra value for filling the background

# Create a filled contour plot
contourf_plot = plt.contourf(longitude, latitude, sar_wind, levels=iso_values_filled, cmap='viridis')

# Convert filled contour polygons to GeoJSON
geojson_data_polygon = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []}

# Normalize iso values for colormap mapping
norm = Normalize(vmin=np.min(iso_values_filled), vmax=np.max(iso_values_filled))

for level, collection in zip(iso_values_filled, contourf_plot.collections):
    for path in collection.get_paths():
        coordinates = path.vertices.tolist()
        # Close the polygon by repeating the first vertex
        coordinates.append(coordinates[0])
        color_hex = to_hex(plt.cm.viridis(norm(level)))  # Map normalized iso value to colormap
        geojson_data_polygon["features"].append({
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [coordinates]
            },
            "properties": {
                "level": level,
                "color": color_hex
            }
        })

# Create a Folium map centered on the average latitude and longitude
center_lat, center_lon = np.mean(latitude), np.mean(longitude)
mymap_polygon = folium.Map(location=[center_lat, center_lon], zoom_start=8)

# Add filled contour polygons as GeoJSON overlay with colored areas
folium.GeoJson(
    geojson_data_polygon,
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': feature['properties']['color'],
        'color': feature['properties']['color'],
        'weight': 2,
        'fillOpacity': 0.7
    }
).add_to(mymap_polygon)

# Display the map with filled contour polygons
mymap_polygon
```

Issue:

contourf_plot gives this map, which the desired result.
[image]

but the folium gives:

[image]

We can see that the polygons are not built.

Objective:
My goal is to convert the filled contour polygons from contourf_plot into GeoJSON format so that I can display them in Folium.

Comment: can you upload the data for reproducing your result?  Which is `sar_wind`, `latitude` and `longitude`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot the contours lines on your first figure, you can find the contours lines are not properly arranged.
[image]
You need to process the contour coordinates, I recommend using [geojsoncontour](https://pypi.org/project/geojsoncontour/).

Just change the codes after the line `contourf_plot = ...` to :

```
import geojsoncontour
import branca

# Create geogson strings
geojson = geojsoncontour.contourf_to_geojson(
    contourf=contourf_plot,
    min_angle_deg=3.0,
    ndigits=5,
    stroke_width=1,
    fill_opacity=0.7)

# Normalize iso values for colormap mapping
norm = Normalize(vmin=np.min(iso_values_filled), vmax=np.max(iso_values_filled))
# Covert float to hex colors
color_hex = []
for level in iso_values_filled: 
    color_hex.append( to_hex(plt.cm.viridis(norm(level))))

# Create a Folium map centered on the average latitude and longitude
center_lat, center_lon = np.mean(latitude), np.mean(longitude)
mymap_polygon = folium.Map(location=[center_lat, center_lon], zoom_start=8)

# Creat colormap
cm = branca.colormap.LinearColormap(color_hex)

# Add filled contour polygons as GeoJSON overlay with colored areas
folium.GeoJson(
    geojson,
    style_function=lambda x: {
        'color':     x['properties']['stroke'],
        'weight':    x['properties']['stroke-width'],
        'fillColor': x['properties']['fill'],
        'fillOpacity':   0.7,
    }).add_to(mymap_polygon)

# Update color map 
mymap_polygon.add_child(cm)
```

You will get result `mymap_polygon`:

[image]